# Some math abaut circle need mathematical formula

Tags: math, geometry

I have no much time to research net, so can somebody derive the formula for calculating the point belonging to the circle?[image]

as u can see we have point 5,-5 and center, and radius and angle. Thanks for advance, i know that isnt programming problem, but I need this to my project. OFC I see thats point 1,-1. but my pc probably will not ;/

Comment: Just hang on a minute, I'll go get the answer for you, don't go away ...

Comment: (x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2   h,k being the center, a point on the circumference should satisfy that equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For points inside the circle with radius R and center X,Y:

point (x,y) is inside the circle if:

(X-x)^2+(Y-y)^2 < R^2

Is that what you're after? No.

So what you need is a translate - rotate - translate.

So X,Y is the centre, x,y is the point and angle is the angle in degrees

```
# Translate
x = x-X ; y = y-Y

# Rotate
rad = angle*M_PI/180
xr =  x*cos(rad) + y*sin(rad)
yr = -x*sin(rad) + y*cos(rad)

x = xr+X ; y = yr +Y
```

So if you only want 90 degrees, replace cos(rad) with 0 and sin(rad) with 1.

Comment: nope, i want to translate point A with axis S about 90 angles,and this point must be on edge circle.